# CodeQL "Reflected server-side cross-site scripting"

Tags: javascript, python, security, github, codeql

When first establishing my GitHub codeql analysis, I have a few results I do not quite understand and would like to understand why they are considered problems.

Second, I have a medium error "Reflected server-side cross-site scripting" which stems from these lines of code

```
@app.route("/api/functions/func/<param>")
def function(param):
    column_translation_from_table, engine, params, group = utils.get_initial_info(request,databases_and_translations,app.logger)
    
    if param == "avg":
        target = value_1
        stmt = select([table.c.value_1, table.c.value_2]).where()
        results = engine.execute(stmt).fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=results[0].keys())

        try:
           output = {
                 "data": df[target].mean(),
                  "name": count
           }
           utils.log_message(request, logger=app.logger, message='data sent successfully', type='info')
         except Exception as e:
               msg = 'data output unsuccessful' +str(e)
               utils.log_message(request, logger=app.logger, message=msg, type='warn')

    return json.dumps(output, cls=JSONEncoder)
```

I do not see how the user input is being taken in any dangerous way in a cross side scripting method.

EDIT

As discussed with Pointy in the comments, the first part of my post(below) likely does not result in any security issues but will be included for reference.

First, the program marked a line

```
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<![A-Za-z\.])${stateAbbr[i]}(?![A-Za-z\.])`, 'g')
```

as "Useless regular-expression character escape." I do not see why this is in any way a vulnerability. The function loops through a predetermined list of states abbreviated as 'Ny' into 'NY.' But CodeQL marked this as a high severity issue in the two times it appears.

Comment: It's probably complaining about the backslash before "." in the character groups. You don't need those.

Comment: Gotcha - I can see why it can be more efficient, but I don't see why it is marked as a High security vulnerability I suppose is what I don't understand

Comment: Yea really that has nothing at all to do with security, or at least not much. The only issue is that (I think) the backslash will be interpreted as a "member" of the character group instead of being ignored as an escape.

Comment: The problem might be that the `\.` appears inside a string literal (not a regex literal), so the \ is silently ignored (the ECMAScript specification seems to call that case [NonEscapeCharacter](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#prod-NonEscapeCharacter)). In your specific case that does not seem to make a difference because the `.` is part of a regex group, but imagine if that was not the case, then instead of matching the literal `.` it would match any character.